# How to combine count and where clause

Tags: mysql

```
 **TableA**
    select    `Contact Email Address`,
               `Contact First Name`
      FROM Test_1


    **Table B**


    select TableA.`Contact Email Address`,
  case when TableA.`Contact Email Address` IS NOT NULL THEN 'Match' 
  ELSE'No Match' 
  END as 'NA'
  from `Table A`
  left JOIN `Products` ON `Table A`.`Contact Email Address`='Products.`Contact Email Address`
```

Trying to get the  two o/p into one single query

```
Select count(*)
  from Table A



SELECT COUNT(*)
    from 'TableB'
    where `NA`= 'No Match'
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want from some sample input data. Your table B doesn't make much sense as there not filer or result from `Products`, the join criteria doesn't make a difference to the result as its a left join.

Answer (score 0):

The following will given counts of matchs/non-matches:

```
select SUM(P.`Contact Email Address` IS NOT NULL) as 'Match',
       SUM(P.`Contact Email Address` IS NULL) as 'No Match,
from `Table A` A
left JOIN Products P
  ON USING (`Contact Email Address`)
group by P.`Contact Email Address`
```